# Facebook Native Ads not showing, error "1011 - Display Format Mismatch"

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

I want to implement the Facebook Audience Network "Native Ads" and display them in a RecyclerView at every Nth position in the list.
I already got the regular banners running in the same app and have no problems there. However, the native ads don't load and I just get a blank rectangle with no content.

When I check the logfile I can see that I keep ending up in "onError" of nativeAd.setAdListener(new NativeAdListener())... getting this error message:

> The display format in the ad request does not match the display
>   format specified for this placement. Each placement can only be used
>   with a single display format. You can create multiple placements in
>   order to use multiple display formats.

My layout XML looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/outer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/outer_padding_listview_item">

<com.facebook.ads.NativeAdLayout
    android:id="@+id/native_ad_container"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder.java

```
public class FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private static final String TAG = FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder.class.getSimpleName();

private final NativeAd nativeAd;
public View view;
private Context context;

@BindView(R.id.outer_layout)
LinearLayout outerLayout;
@BindView(R.id.native_ad_container)
NativeAdLayout nativeAdContainer;

public FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder(View view, Context context) {
    super(view);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    this.view = view;
    this.context = context;

    nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, Konstanten.FACEBOOK_AUDIENCE_NETWORK_NATIVE_AD_IN_RECYCLER_VIEW);

    nativeAd.setAdListener(new NativeAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError(): " + adError.getErrorMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder onAdLoaded()");

            // Render the Native Ad Template
            View adView = NativeAdView.render(context, nativeAd);
            // Add the Native Ad View to your ad container.
            // The recommended dimensions for the ad container are:
            // Width: 280dp - 500dp
            // Height: 250dp - 500dp
            // The template, however, will adapt to the supplied dimensions.
            nativeAdContainer.addView(adView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 800));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder onAdClicked()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder onLoggingImpression()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMediaDownloaded(Ad ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookNativeAdListViewItemHolder onMediaDownloaded()");
        }
    });

    // Initiate a request to load an ad.
    nativeAd.loadAd();
}
```

}

It all builds fine and I can see the rectangle in the recyclerview where the native ad should be displayed. But the problem is that it just remains white and there's no content displayed (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I am facing the same issue in ios 14.7.1 device

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a testing device to show ads

1. Go to your [Monetization Manager](https://business.facebook.com/pub/testing) from navigation menu select Integration --> Testing
2. Enable Testing and check on 'Use real advertiser content'
3. Now add your testing device by adding 'Google Advertiser Id' from your 'Settings->Google Account->Ads'

[Click here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing) for more information

Comment: Have tried the testing option already and unfortunately it didn't change anything about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to find the problem. The problem was the wrong ad format (rectangle instead of natvie-ad) and therefore wasn't able to display an ad in a native ad container.